# How to output this XML as a ranking?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML:

```
<bookings>

  <booking>
    <event>Christmas Party</event>
    <source>Internet</source>
  </booking>

  <booking>
    <event>Church day</event>
    <source>Television</source>
  </booking>

  <booking>
    <event>Port Anniversary</event>
    <source>Television</source>
  </booking>

  <booking>
    <event>Disco Fever</event>
    <source>Internet</source>
  </booking>

  <booking>
    <event>Party Night</event>
    <source>Internet</source>
  </booking>

  <booking>
    <event>Christmas Party</event>
    <source>Flyer</source>
  </booking>    

</bookings>
```

And I need to output it like this:

> Top marketing sources for bookings:
>
> 1. Internet: 3 booking(s)
> 2. Television: 2 booking(s)
> 3. Flyer: 1 booking(s)

Is that even possible with XSLT?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have tried yourself using XSL? Where do you get the amount of bookings from? *edit* uh, sorry. Got it. ignore my second question ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual answer for this sort of thing in XSLT 1.0 is *Muenchian grouping*.  First define a key

```
<xsl:key name="bookingsBySource" match="booking" use="source" />
```

Then use the following trick to iterate over the unique source values

```
<xsl:template match="/bookings">
  <ol>
    <xsl:for-each select="booking[generate-id() =
            generate-id(key('bookingsBySource', source)[1])]">
      <!-- sort by number of bookings, largest first -->
      <xsl:sort select="count(key('bookingsBySource', source))"
                data-type="number"
                order="descending" />
      <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="source"/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('bookingsBySource', source))" />
        <xsl:text> booking(s)</xsl:text>
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ol>
</xsl:template>
```

The for-each select pulls out only the first `booking` element for each `source` value.

Comment: There is one small extension required: `<xsl:value-of select="position()"/><xsl:text>. </xsl:text>` to get the expected output.

Comment: @hr_117 I meant to use an `<ol>` (which is automatically numbered) rather than `<ul>`.  I've fixed this now.